# Unquote a java method in clojure

Tags: java, methods, clojure, quote, clojure-java-interop

How do I parameterize calls methods in Clojure?

Example:

```
(def url (java.net.URL. "http://www.google.com"))
(.getHost url) ;; works!
(def host '.getHost)
(host url) ;; Nope :(
(~host url) ;; Nope :(
(eval `(~host url)) ;; Works :s
```

Comment: Since `'.getHost` isn't a "quoted method" to begin with, you can't unquote it. It's just a symbol. Besides, you seem to have already worked out how to evaluate your symbol into a method call, so what's the question?

Comment: That last line scared me good! Happy Halloween!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right solution:

```clj
(def url (URL. "http://www.google.com"))
(def host 'getHost)
(defn dynamic-invoke
  [obj method arglist]
  (.invoke (.getDeclaredMethod
             (class obj) (name method) nil)
           obj (into-array arglist)))
(dynamic-invoke url host [])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to create an alias for an existing function, a wrapper function is all you need:

```
> (ns clj (:import [java.net URL]))
> (def url (URL. "http://www.google.com"))
> (defn host [arg] (.getHost arg))
> (host url)
;=> "www.google.com"
```

While you could use `memfn` as pointed out by another user, it seems less obvious what is going on.  Indeed, even clojure.org recommends against it now:

---

https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop

> `(memfn method-name arg-names)*`
>
> Macro. Expands into code that creates a fn that expects to be 
>   passed an object and any args and calls the named instance method on
>   the object passing the args. Use when you want to treat a Java method
>   as a first-class fn.

```
(map (memfn charAt i) ["fred" "ethel" "lucy"] [1 2 3])
-> (\r \h \y)
```

> Note it almost always preferable to do this directly now, with syntax like:

```
(map #(.charAt %1 %2) ["fred" "ethel" "lucy"] [1 2 3])
-> (\r \h \y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to parametrize a method on a Java class is:

```
#(.method fixed-object %)
```

or

```
#(.method % fixed argument)
```

or if neither the object or the arguments are fixed.

```
#(.method %1 %2)
```

Often used with higher order functions line map, filter and reduce.

```
(map #(.getMoney %) customers)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `memfn`:

```
(def url (java.net.URL. "http://www.google.com"))
(def host (memfn getHost))
(host url)
```

Comment: I had forgotten about `memfn`.

Comment: memfn was depricated in the Clojure 1.0 era. It was replaced by the #(.methodname thing args args) form

Comment: Source for this Arthur?